# How to use mutate_if in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to create a loop to calculate relative elemental levels for each fish in this dataset (relative elemental levels will be calculated by x/mean(x) in order to divide each data point by the mean of the entire column. I have all the fish in one dataframe but they can be filtered out by ID (see head of data frame) 1st fish is Ring10_1_2. Here is my current code and the current error I am getting.

```
raw_data <- read_csv("Hatch5Reg.csv")

fishIDs = unique(raw_data$ID)

Hatch5_Rel_El = list()
for(ID in fishIDs) {
  Hatch5_Rel_El[[ID]] = lapply(raw_data %>% filter(ID == ID_) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric),funs(mod = x / mean(x)))
  
}

#Error in match.fun(FUN) : 'funs(mod = x/mean(x))' is not a function, character or symbol
```

[image: head of raw_data]

Answer (score 1):

Since no sample data is provided, please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), the following would work on iris data:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x /mean(.x)))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1      0.8727895   1.1447885    0.3725386  0.16675931     setosa
2      0.8385625   0.9812473    0.3725386  0.16675931     setosa
3      0.8043354   1.0466638    0.3459287  0.16675931     setosa
4      0.7872219   1.0139555    0.3991485  0.16675931     setosa
5      0.8556760   1.1774967    0.3725386  0.16675931     setosa
6      0.9241301   1.2756215    0.4523683  0.33351862     setosa
```

BTW, `mutate_if` has been superseded by using `across` in the more recent `dplyr` versions.

Comment: Hi @Lennyy thank you for sending this example. This is exactly what I want to do but I would want it to only run on data by species. So for this example you would get three separate  lists for each species setosa,, virginica etc..

Comment: Your welcome. For that purpose you could just add a `group_by(Species)` before the `mutate`.